# AOP around not working in JAVA with Annotation

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

there is one java class "Test2" contains 4-5 methods and in only 1 method(notifyTransferStatus) i want to put eventable annotation as. There is no problem in method execution but annotation is not working.

```
@Eventable(name = TransferStatus)
    public ResponseEntity<String> notifyTransferStatus(EventRequest request) {
//method execution successfully 

JSONObject  jsonRequestPayload = createJsonData(callEvent, transferStatus, request);
            LOG.info("jsonRequestPayload created successfully");

clientResponse = transferUtil.notify(transferStatusUrl, jsonRequestPayload);

}
```

Corresponding Aspect class.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Around("(execution(* com.test.Test1.*(..))" +
            "|| execution(* com.test.Test2.*(..))" +
            ")" + " && @annotation(eventableAnnotation)")
    public Object eventProcessingAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint,  Eventable eventableAnnotation) throws Throwable {
//some logic for handling annotation
// use name if provided
    if (eventableAnnotation.name() != null) {
        eventId = eventableAnnotation.name();
        counterName = eventId;
    }
}
```

So, above method "notifyTransferStatus" is part of class Test2 and annotation not working, logic executed perfectly inside method.

But There is Test1.java which contains only one method and with annotation its working fine.

So basic difference is one class contains only 1 method and other class contains 4-5 methods.

Comment: Just a quick query, is one class final and the other isn't?

Comment: No final class here

Comment: Could you also post the Test1 and Test2 code here? Maybe something is missing in the information here.

Comment: Please post some more code including package and class declarations, there can be problems in each of those. And are your test classes Spring `@Component`s? Do they implement interfaces or not? How is Spring AOP configured? And what about your `eventProcessingAdvice`? It should return an object, but does not. It also does not `proceed()` to the intercepted method. Help others to help you by making it easier to understand the whole setup. Ideally, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).